# How to reuse C# enum in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am having the following sample enum in my Mvc application and I need to reuse it in Power-Shell.

```
namespace namespace_name  
{
   public enum test  
   {  
      sample1,  
      sample2  
   }  
}
```

I need to use the above enum in PowerShell. I have come across the following link, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26436.how-to-create-and-use-enums-in-powershell.aspx .

I don't know how to use the enum defined by us, please provide a way to use this in Power-Shell.

Comment: Import the dependency and then you can use the fully qualified name to access it (eg: `[namespace_name.test.sample1]`) I think

Comment: What do you mean "I don't know how to use the enum"? The Technet article you linked even has an example.

Comment: @Icepickle almost, `[namespace_name.test]::sample1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, my knowledge of powershell is extremely rusty :)

Answer (score 2):

The link in your question has the answer...

> PowerShell allows to define a enum using the Add-Type cmdlet. Once the
>   enum type has been added to the console environment, it can not be
>   removed or re-defined? Closing and re-opening the console will remove
>   the enum.
>
> Enums are used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type that
>   consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list. By
>   default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each
>   successive enumerator is increased by 1.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   public enum test
   {
      sample1,
      sample2
   }
"@
```